# Get href string of certain links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

With beautifulSoup, I would like to get the strings associated with certain href which have "/genre/" in them. For example, I have the following href which I got using the following command:

```
soup.find_all('a', href=True)
```

And the output is:

```
 <a href="/genre/Animation?ref_=tt_stry_gnr"> Animation</a>,
 <a href="/genre/Adventure?ref_=tt_stry_gnr"> Adventure</a>,
 <a href="/genre/Family?ref_=tt_stry_gnr"> Family</a>,
 <a href="/title/tt0235917/parentalguide?ref_=tt_stry_pg#certification"> See all certifications</a>,
 <a href="/title/tt0235917/parentalguide?ref_=tt_stry_pg" itemprop="url"> View content advisory</a>,
```

However, I would like to select **only** "genre" as links and get the output as:

```
Animation
Adventure
Family
```

I tried using:

```
import re
imdb_page.find_all('a', {'href': re.compile(r'/genre/\d.*')})
```

But I get an empty array. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a mistake in the the regex, it should be

```
>>> for a in soup.find_all('a', {'href': re.compile(r'^/genre/.*')}):
...     print a.text
... 
 Animation
 Adventure
 Family
```

**Regex Explanation**

- `^` Anchors the pattern at the start of the string,
- `/genre/` Matches `genre`
- `.*` Matches anything

**What is wrong in `/genre/\d.*`**

- `\d` matches any digit. That is you are trying to match a digit after the `/genre/` ( like `href="/genre/1qwert"` ).

  But in the input string, no `href` follows this pattern.

  Hence you get an empty string.